# How can I put an IKEA "Expedit" shelf 75 cm above the floor?

Tags: walls, mounting, shelving

I have a 4x4 IKEA expedit shelf (which is ~150cm x ~150cm in size) and want to put it 75cm above the floor, so that it lines up with the head-side of a bed. Its back would face the wall, like this:

```
+-+
|/|
+-+
|/|     <- Shelf
+-+
|/|
+-+ 
|/|
+-+
   #
   #
   #\
   #===========================\     <- Bed
   #            #             #|

 ^- What to put here, below the shelf?
```

On the ASCII-art picture, the shelf is midair. What could I put below the shelf so that it's fixed and won't break up if it is charged with books and stuff?

The wall is labile and I guess it can't secure the shelf all by itself.

Comment: Can you explain "wall is labile"? I'm not familiar with that phrase.

Comment: also: Expedit wall mounting tips: http://www.ikeahackers.net/2013/01/how-to-mount-a-safe-floating-2-x-4-expedit-shelf.html

Comment: @da0 i am sorry i am not a native speaker. I mean that it is not a concrete wall.